# Customizing dialog box in android

Tags: android, eclipse

This is my piece of code for exit message in dialog box.I want to customize it. i.e. change it's colour,text width,font size of text etc,background etc.Please can someone tell me how to do it?

```
public void addListenerOnButton2()
{ 

    exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        MainActivity.this);
 alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("EXIT?");
 alertDialogBuilder
 .setMessage("Do you want to quit?")
 .setCancelable(false)
 .setPositiveButton("YES",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
 {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) 
     {     
      MainActivity.this.finish();
     }
   })
   .setNegativeButton("NO",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
   {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) 
        {
         dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
 AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
 alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Use dialog instead of AlertDialog for this..

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android

Comment: Can'tt I do this in this code itself?

Answer (score 2):

Create your dialog layout as xml file, get a layoutinflator from your context, when you try to show the custom dialog, inflate the layout from xml and set it to your alertdialog object.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void showDialog(String title, String message){
        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);        
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_dialog, null);
        TextView tvDialogTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_user_dialog_header);
        tvDialogTitle.setText(title);   
        dialog.setCustomTitle(v);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    dialog.setMessage(message);

    dialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

please refer above code for making custom dialog. Here, I have set the custom title, but with this reference, u can customize your own dialog according your custom layout.

Hope this can be useful for your problem.

Comment: I want to set the color,font size and dialog box size.What you Have said is already done by me.

Comment: In your custom layout, u can define all that parameters.